# Laravel hosting server public folder and storage link issue

Tags: laravel

If i'm trying to put my laravel project in server. I have faced two problem :

1. Storage link not working
2. It is must to do move all public folder files into outside?

Comment: What seem to be the error? Permission error? What is the behavior of the system when the storage link is not working?

Comment: What kind of production server are you using? Is it a shared hosting or something like DigitalOcean or Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

Usually I have to move the public folder outside the project, you're right.

```
/root
../app
../public
```

And then, in the index.php in the public folder, you will change

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/../app/vendor/autoload.php';
```

and

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: it made my site go down

Answer (score 0):

For proper problem solving please provide with the actual error by attaching screenshots.
From my assumption of your problem:

1. Please give your `storage` folder proper permission.
2. In shared hosting, it is sometimes required to move your resource folders like images, css, js from `public` folder to root folder in case of C-Panel in the `public_html` folder.

Comment: You can change the domain's document root path in cPanel. I really don't support the idea of restructuring your project folders.

Comment: you need to change index.php file else it will give error

Comment: Thank you..But actually I made storage link in local ,its working fine I can access image file using assets.But when I'm hosting into server,storage link shortcut doesn't appear.Image file also not displaying..

Answer (score 0):

Bellow steps can help you:
 (after uploading your project)

1. put the all of codes/files in out of /public_html directory، like:
   (maybe its be different from what you see in your host, not important)

```
/.php
/backups
/domains
        /YourDomain.ir
                      /.htpasswd
                      /logs
                      /private_html
                      /public_html
                      /stats
                      /LaravelApp
/imap
```

2. move your `public` from LaravelApp to `public_html`.
3. edit `index.php` to:

```
require __DIR__.'/../LaravelApp/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../LaravelApp/bootstrap/app.php';
```

4. if your  shared hosting provider has not `.ENV` permission, paste your env in `config/*`

tls: never ever put your  `. env` file in public directory!